# LINK : fatal error LNK1000 when linking static lib to C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, static-libraries

I am getting LINK : `fatal error LNK1000: unknown error at 00007FF62BCB3572; consult documentation for technical support options`
when linking a static library with my project. I have made sure that this library is built with -vcvars_ver=14.0 and /MD flag just as my project.

One interesting thing is when this static lib is built on my machine it links without any error, but when its built on different machine it throws this error.

Comment: Did you mean you build the static lib with the same version of Visual Studio on another machine, then copy it over to your machine for linking and that is when it failed to link?

Comment: Yes that is correct.